# Retrieve a Validator from FacesContext

Tags: jsf, validation, facescontext

I was wondering if it is possible to retrieve a `Validator` from the `FacesContext` as i can retrieve the ids from there. by doing this:

```
Iterator<String> ids = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                .getApplication().getValidatorIds();
```

I would now like to get a `Validator` by using those ids. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().createValidator(java.lang.String validatorId);
```

See [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/Application.html#createValidator%28java.lang.String%29).